# Problem with realloc implementation resulting in Access violation

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a custom string class that malloc/realloc/free's internally; For certain strings appending works fine, but on certain others it will **always** fail (small or large allocations). The same code worked fine on a different project, although it was an ANSI build.

I believe I'm implementing this correctly, but most likely I've overlooked something. The error occurs when I attempt to utilize the "szLog" buffer once the log has been opened. This simply contains the path to the program files directory (40 characters total). Using this same buffer without the "Log file '" prefix works fine, so it's an issue with the realloc section. And yes, the log does open properly.

I get *0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00660063.* only when realloc is used (but as previously stated, it doesn't always fail - in this situation, when szLog is input - but other variable strings/buffers do it too).

**HeapReAlloc** is the failing function inside realloc.c, errno being 22.

I've stripped the comments to try and keep the post as small as possible! Any help would be much appreciated.

*gData.szLogStr* is a UString, *IsNull* is a definition for "*x == NULL*" and *unichar* is simply a typedef for wchar_t

```
class UString : public Object
{
private:
    unichar*    mpsz;
    unichar*    mpszPrev;
    UINT        muiAlloc;
    UINT        muiLen;
public:
    ... other functions ...

    UString& operator << (const unichar* pszAdd)
    {
        if ( IsNull(pszAdd) )
            return (*this);
        if ( IsNull(mpsz) )
        {
            muiAlloc = ((str_length(pszAdd)+1) * sizeof(unichar));
            if ( IsNull((mpsz = static_cast<unichar*>(malloc(muiAlloc)))) )
            {
                SETLASTERROR(ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);
                muiAlloc = 0;
                return (*this);
            }
            mpszPrev = mpsz;
            muiLen = str_copy(mpsz, pszAdd, muiAlloc);
        }
        else
        {
            UINT    uiNewAlloc = (muiAlloc + (str_length(pszAdd) * sizeof(unichar)));

            if ( muiAlloc < uiNewAlloc )
            {
                uiNewAlloc *= 2;

                /* Fails */
                if ( IsNull((mpsz = static_cast<unichar*>(realloc(mpsz, uiNewAlloc)))) )
                {
                    SETLASTERROR(ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY);
                    mpsz = mpszPrev;
                    return (*this);
                }
                mpszPrev = mpsz;
                muiAlloc = uiNewAlloc;
            }
            muiLen = str_append(mpsz, pszAdd, muiAlloc);
        }
        return (*this);
    }
```

and this being called from within main via:

```
        UString     szConf;
        unichar     szLog[MAX_LEN_GENERIC];

        szConf << ppszCmdline[0];
        szConf.replace(_T(".exe"), _T(".cfg"));
        if ( GetPrivateProfileString(_T("Application"), _T("LogFile"), NULL, szLog, sizeofbuf(szLog), szConf.str()) == 0 )
        {
            UINT    uiLen = str_copy(szLog, szConf.str(), sizeofbuf(szLog)); 
            szLog[uiLen-3] = 'l';
            szLog[uiLen-2] = 'o';
            szLog[uiLen-1] = 'g';
        }

        if ( ApplicationLog::Instance().Open(szLog, CREATE_ALWAYS) )
        {
            gData.szLogStr.clear();
            /* Erroring call */
            gData.szLogStr << _T("Log file '") << szLog << _T("' opened");
            APP_LOG(LL_WriteAlways, NULL, gData.szLogStr);
            ObjMgr::Instance().DumpObjects(LogDumpedObjects);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are programming in c++, so use `new` and `delete`. To 'renew', allocate a new memory area large enough to hold the new string, initialize it with the correct values and then `delete` the old string.

Comment: You are programming in C++, so use `vector` ;-p

Comment: For some purposes, `realloc` does provide a real advantage that neither `new` nor `vector` (with the default allocator) can match. The caveat there is important though: if you want to control allocation, just write an allocator, not the rest of the class.

Comment: @Steve: You could expand that to "You are programming in C++, so use `std::string`" ;) But for learning purposes, writing ones own string class is really helpful.

Comment: I'm globally overriding new/delete (and occasionally log their contents, using these strings for simplicity). Therefore I don't want to use new/deletes from within the string class. I know I can override it for the class only, but working with the 'old' styles keeps me in shape for when I need to use them elsewhere, as I usually code "C with classes"-style. The std:: strings lack certain functionality I require, and rather than overloading them I can optimize as best as possible using a custom class.

Answer (score 0):

What is str_length() returning when it fails? I'd trace the value of muiAlloc and see what you're actually trying to allocate. It may not be a sane number.

Are you certain that whatever's in szLog is null-terminated, and that the buffer has room for whatever you're copying into it? It's not clear if str_copy is safe or not. It may be a wrapper around strncpy(), which does not guarantee a null terminator, but some people mistakenly assume it does.

Comment: I've already validated the str_xxx calls return values (they return as expected), and str_copy is pretty much identical to openbsd's strlcpy - it returns the number of characters written to the buffer, excluding the terminating null. str_length() returns 40, as expected, and muiAlloc is at 22 when entering the realloc call (uiNewAlloc reaches 204, due to the doubling of the buffer size). These are all as expected.

Comment: Another point I just thought of, though I doubt this is relevant: Don't ever assign to p[n-3] without first making sure n is greater than 2! Also, in the on-realloc branch there (where it's not crashing), you've got muiLen = str_copy(mpsz, pszAdd, muiAlloc); -- but muiAlloc is bytes, not chars. If it's Unicode, that's a bug. Actually, hang on, I see you're always passing bytes to str_copy()'s  last argument: Is it supposed to be bytes, rather than a character count?

Comment: Ah yes, the classic validation of buffers! Have added the check to make sure uiLen > 0 in that scope. muiLen is the number of characters (i.e. wcslen), whereas muiAlloc is the number of bytes allocated (and str_copy receives the size of the buffer). Assuming wcslen(L"123") is the same as strlen("123"), which they are, there's not a problem. I admit my overall unicode 'handling' is poor however :)

Comment: Signalling the difference between 'characters' and 'bytes' is a perfect application for Apps Hungarian notation (instead of just encoding the static type 'unsigned int').

Comment: As for the problem itself: I'd add diagnostics to print the addresses and sizes of the buffers involved (szLog, mpsz, etc) and relate that to the memory address given in the error message as well as to the length and size of the strings involved.

Comment: Thanks Lars, I'll change the style to accommodate things like that in future. Was hoping I'd made an obvious mistake that someone else would be able to spot, but looks like I'll have to check the sizes and everything else for every possibility! Cheers :)

Comment: I'd define IsNull() as a function, or get rid of it. If x appears more than once in the text of the macro, the entire call to malloc() or realloc() will be duplicated. Macros are dangerous for that reason. And you're passing a buffer size to the nSize parameter of GetPrivateProfileString() (is it actually calling GetPrivateProfileStringA() or GetPrivateProfileStringW()?), which is a character count, not a buffer size. This is why your string functions should always take character counts rather than buffer sizes: Because everybody else's do, and you can so easily get the semantics mixed up.

Comment: In this case, if GetPrivateProfileStringW is the function being called, you're passing n characters worth of buffer, and describing its size as n*2.